# does gitlab api allow cherry pick from one repository to another

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I need to cherry-pick a commit from repository A to repository B
I wonder if gitlab's cherry-pick api will work between two different repositories

some thing like below

curl --location --request POST ‘https://{{host}}/api/v4/projects/{{project-id-b}/repository/commits/{{branchB}}/cherry_pick’ \

–header ‘Private-Token: token’ \

–form ‘id=“project-id-a”’ \

–form ‘sha=“commitSHA”’ \

–form ‘branch=“branch-a”’

Answer (score 0):

No, the [cherry pick a commit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#cherry-pick-a-commit) only allows you to specify the one project.

I suggest [submitting a feature request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues) if there isn't one already.